# How to debug a PhantomJS script?

Tags: phantomjs

My script has some syntax error but instead of showing the error, PhantomJS doesn't display anything. Why Phantom JS isn't showing parse error if he script has errors?

In the following PhantomJS script (running via windows CMD), phantomJs hangs instead of showing error if there is a parsing error in the script.

```
var system = require('system');
var webpage = require('webpage').create();

console.log('starting script');

if (system.args.length === 0) {
    console.log('no args');
} else {
    system.args.forEach(function(arg,index){
        console.log('arg is '+arg+' at '+index);
    });
}

webpage.open('http://localhost:3000/cookie-demo',function(status){
    if (status === 'success'){
        console.log('success in opening page');
        phantom.cookies.forEach(function(cookie,index){
            for ( var key in cookie){
```

**`/*if instead of index, I use i as variable (undefined), the script just hangs!*/`**

```
console.log('[cookie:'+index+']'+key+'='+'cookie[key]');
        }
    });
    phantom.exit(0);
}
else{
    console.log('could not open the page');
    phantom.exit(1);
}
```

});

If there is no syntax error in the script, I get following output

```
C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\programs\random>phantomjs --cookies-file=cookie-jar.txt phantomTest.js
starting script
arg is phantomTest.js at 0
success in opening page
[cookie:0]domain=cookie[key]
[cookie:0]expires=cookie[key]
[cookie:0]expiry=cookie[key]
[cookie:0]httponly=cookie[key]
[cookie:0]name=cookie[key]
[cookie:0]path=cookie[key]
[cookie:0]secure=cookie[key]
[cookie:0]value=cookie[key]
[cookie:1]domain=cookie[key]
[cookie:1]expires=cookie[key]
[cookie:1]expiry=cookie[key]
[cookie:1]httponly=cookie[key]
[cookie:1]name=cookie[key]
[cookie:1]path=cookie[key]
[cookie:1]secure=cookie[key]
[cookie:1]value=cookie[key]
```

But if there is a syntax error, I see nothing on the console and it doesnt exit

```
C:\Users\Manu\Documents\manu\programs\random>phantomjs --cookies-file=cookie-jar.txt phantomTest.js
```

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I have modified the description.

Comment: Still I dont see a question, but rather a bug description.

Comment: added the question. Basically, why Phantom JS isn't showing parse error if he script has errors? How do I debug phantomJS script?

Comment: Tried your script and don't see such behaviour. Usually it would hang if there indeed is a syntax error in the code, but using undefined var is not a syntax error, you probably have a typo somewhere. What PhantomJS version?

Comment: 2.1.1. Is there a way to avoid PhantomJS from hanging and report and error? Regarding undefined, is there a better way to find such error instead of reviewing/debugging code?

Comment: No, it's a bug of the version. Instead of debugging code you can use [static code analysis tools](https://gist.github.com/listochkin/6250151), And instead of writing... well, no. Still gotta write it, man.

Comment: `No, it's a bug of the version. ` - Is there a version of PhantomJS which hasn't got this bug?

Comment: v 1.9.8 and lower or 2.5b signal of syntax errors

Comment: Thanks. Can you please put your comment as answer. I'll accept it. BTW, I didnt see 2.5b in releases. Where could I download it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS version 2.0 and 2.1 will silently fail and hang if there are syntax errors. Use versions 1.9.8 or 2.5 betas. All downloads are here: https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/

Better still migrate to [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) which is a project with very similar API that uses headless Google Chrome underneath.